# Any way to determine which text message is being responded to?

Tags: sms, twilio

I use Twilio with my team management system. A text message is automatically sent out for each game. The receiver can then reply with YES or NO. My issue is that when I send two text messages, I have no way to tell if the reply is for the first message I sent, or the second.

Does Twilio have any way to determine which text message it was a response to?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are sending two messages from one Twilio number to the same user number there is nothing within the SMS specification that allows a user to reply to a specific message, so there is nothing you can do with Twilio to detect that.

If you are sending two messages to two different numbers and you get replies from those numbers, you can match against the from number and see what [the last message sent from that number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters) was and attach the reply to that.

Alternatively, if you want to get replies from one user to different messages, you could send them from different Twilio numbers. That way you can match the outgoing number to the message and the answer. This is mostly used for [phone number masking to enable anonymous communications and there is a good tutorial available on this in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/php/laravel).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ah ha! I hadn't thought of multiple numbers. I'll have to take a look at that tutorial. That could be the perfect solution.

Comment: Awesome, let me know if you have any questions about this.